# HAR file logging with ELK stack

Tags: visualization, logstash, kibana, har

Has anyone had any success visualizing .HAR (httparchive) files in Kibana? Har files seem to be in json format, hoping there is a shortcut there but just guessing. I am pretty new to to the ELK stack.

Curious if anyone had any attempts or successes before reinventing the wheel. My goal is to be able to index these files for regression to trend on specific requests.

Thanks in advance for any help!